# Filtering on foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I generate QuerySet as follows:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Article.objects.filter(foreignkey=self.kwargs['value'])
```

The value is generated like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'someview' value %}">anchor</a>
url(r'^(?P<value>\w+)/$', someview.as_view(), name='someview')
```

When value is integer then everything works, but when I pass value as a string I receive:

```
ValueError: "invalid literal for int() with base 10"
```

Comment: What string are you passing and what do you expect `filter()` on `ForeignKey` to do? Thanks.

Comment: try using foreignkey__pk=self.kwargs['value'] or even foreignkey=ForeignClass.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['value'])

Comment: Where is the get_queryset method?

Comment: I have to pass string value, so that it appears in browser as a string  e.g. www.example.com/value/ and not as www.example.com/22/

Comment: It is in class someview(generic.ListView):

Comment: @nickbusted So you are passing string to foreign keys primary key which is int by default. What is your foreign key? Does it have any fields that store your value? If so try to filter with foreignkey__valuefield=self.kwargs['value'].

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! Would you please write the same thing as an answer so I will officially accept it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing string to the foreign key's primary key which is integer by default. If you want to filter based on foreign key field use

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Article.objects.filter(foreignkey__valuefield=self.kwargs['value'])
```

Source
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model